# django user profiles and different views

Tags: python, django

I'm building a CRM system and i want to have two types of users

Administrator (More than 5 users)
Supervisor (One person)

Administrator will capture details in a django form, save it, and only have access to see their own work.
A Supervisor will have a view of all Administrators captured work from the CRM, in a form of a list and all the of details the administrators.

Question: How do i create two different types of users and how do i display the different types of views (Administrator = Their own work only, and Supervisor = All of the Administrators work).

App One for users

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UsersModels(models.Model):
    Role = [
        ('Agent','Agent'),
        ('Manager','Manager'),
    ]
    TheUser = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Rank = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Role, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.TheUser
```

App Two

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class ExperimentalModels(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

Views is

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . models import ExperimentalModels
from . forms import ExperimentalForms
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
def Edit(request, details_id):
    Details_Edit = ExperimentalModels.objects.get(pk=details_id)
    The_form_edit = ExperimentalForms(request.POST or None, instance=Details_Edit)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if The_form_edit.is_valid():
            The_form_edit.save()
    return render(request, 'Experiment/Edit.html',
                  {'The_form_edit':The_form_edit,
                   'Details_Edit':Details_Edit})

def Details(request, details_id):
    Details_list = ExperimentalModels.objects.get(pk=details_id)
    return render(request, 'Experiment/Details.html',
                  {'Details_list':Details_list})

def Home(request):
    ExperimentList = ExperimentalModels.objects.get(id=User)
    return render(request, 'Experiment/Home.html',
                  {'ExperimentList':ExperimentList})

def Database(request):
    The_form = ExperimentalForms
    if request.method == 'POST':
        The_form = ExperimentalForms(request.POST)
        if The_form.is_valid():
            The_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ("Addition Done!"))
            return redirect('Home')
    return render(request, 'Experiment/Database.html',{'The_form':The_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user_passes_test` decorator.

```py
def user_is_manager(user):
    return user.UsersModels.rank == "Manager"

def user_is_agent(user):
    return user.usersmodels.rank == "Agent"

@user_passes_test(user_is_manager)
def Edit(request, details_id):
    ...

@user_passes_test(user_is_agent)
def Edit(request, details_id):
    ...
```